# sections appear in header which has table style

Tags: table-of-contents, header-footer, fancyhdr

I have a problem with the **header** in **table format** and picture as a logo which section titles appear as part of the header in each page. Can anyone say why this has happened?
[image]

[image]

```
\documentclass[a4paper,12pt]{article}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[demo]{graphicx}
\usepackage{hyperref}
\usepackage{array}
\usepackage{lastpage}
\usepackage{lipsum}
\usepackage{helvet}
\renewcommand{\familydefault}{\sfdefault}
\usepackage{fancyhdr}
\usepackage[hmargin=2cm,top=4cm,headheight=1 in,footskip=0.9 cm]{geometry}
\setlength{\parindent}{0.95cm}
\pagestyle{fancy}
\renewcommand{\headrulewidth}{0pt}
%\fancyhead[CE,CO,LE,LO,RE,RO]{} %% clear out all headers
\fancyhead[C]{
                \begin{tabular}{|m{5cm} m{5.5cm} m{5cm}|l }
            \multicolumn{1}{l}{}                       &        & \multicolumn{1}{r}{\includegraphics[height=1.2cm,width=5cm]{image3.jpeg}} &   \\ 
            \cline{1-3}
            Company  & Owner  & Description &   \\
            AAAAA  & Test  & Technical Specification   &   \\
            \begin{tabular}[c]{@{}l@{}}\\
            \end{tabular} &        &      &   \\
            Doc No.   & Revision  & Date  &   \\
            BBBBBB  & A         & \today &   \\
            \cline{1-3}
        \end{tabular}
    }
\cfoot{}
\rfoot{page \thepage\ of \pageref{LastPage}}
\begin{document}


\vspace*{2cm}
%%% first page revision control

\noindent\begin{tabular}{|m{5cm} m{5.5cm} m{5cm}|l }
    \multicolumn{1}{l}{}                       &        & \multicolumn{1}{r}{} &   \\ 
    \cline{1-3}
    Author  & Checked  & Approved &   \\
    AAAAAA  & BBBBBBBB  & AAAAAAAAA   &   \\
    \begin{tabular}[c]{@{}l@{}}\\
    \end{tabular} &        &      &   \\
    Revision History   & Action  & Responsible  &   \\
    BBBBBBB  & NNNNNNNN         & MMMMMM &   \\
    \cline{1-3}
\end{tabular}


\tableofcontents

\newpage

\section{General}
\subsection{Nomenclature}
\subsection{Reference Documents}
\subsection{Objective and Scope}
\subsection{System Overview}
\section{System Functionality}
\subsection{Function Relations}
\subsection{Function Descriptions}
\subsection{Functional Matrix for Subsystems}
\subsection{Interfaces Between Subsystems}
\section{Realization}
\subsection{Basic Hardware Choices}
\subsection{Basic Software Choices}
\subsection{Function Matrix For System Modules}
\subsection{Interfaces between System Modules}
\section{Interface to the Environment}
\subsection{Interface to other Hardware}
\subsubsection{First Connector}
\subsubsection{Second Connector}
\subsection{Interface to other Software}
\subsubsection{First Signal Group}
\subsubsection{Second Signal Group}




%\lipsum[1-30]

\end{document}
```

Answer (score 3):

By default, your document has headers on the left and the right.
You overwrite the `[C]` header, so you specify the content at the center of the header, but this does not change the separate left and right parts of the header. To avoid them, you can clear out all headers before setting you own. You already have a line for this,

```
%\fancyhead[CE,CO,LE,LO,RE,RO]{} %% clear out all headers
```

Just uncomment it by deleting the first `%`.